# Syncing an outlook calendar to Sharepoint

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-calendar

So I'm struggling with this,

Everything I find on internet is sharepoint to outlook... i want to sync my events from outlook to sharepoint. Creating an event in outlook calendar and then syncing it to sharepoint calendar. Right now the only solution i found is copying all the event from my outlook calendar and paste them into sharepoint using outlook... that's not syncing. Is it even possible to really sync anything from outlok TO sharepoint.

I have Sharepoint 2013.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is sync, but what you can do is to overlay the Outlook calendar over Sharepoint calendar. Have a look at the steps for SP2010: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/05/31/sharepoint-and-exchange-calendar-together.aspx. Steps for 2013: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4CAEBE59-3994-4A94-9322-B31ABB8A5E9A

Comment: it says there was no endpoint listening at. And i know that the exchange url is good cause we are using it in another application. I tried that too but forgot to mention in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync a SharePoint list calendar to Outlook (using Internet Explorer)

As far as I know, **it is not possible** to sync an Outlook calendar to SharePoint **out of the box**.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can sync using Power Automate. The SharePoint Calendar is a SharePoint list with the name "Calendar". It's a simple PowerAutomate workflow with few steps which you can set up in a few minutes. In case you want to use a Shared Mailbox you can sync the calendar from therein when you share this calendar with your personal mailbox. Then you will see it in Power Automate shown as Calendar to retrieve events from.

Please note: SharePoint Item Action in Power Automate doesn't support all SharePoint List field types, e.g. checkboxes like "All Day Event". Nevertheless you can sync All Day Events which will show up with scheduled time 12pm-12pm.

You can also include SharePoint Calendars as SharePoint Web Part e.g. in a SharePoint Page.